# async javascript/nodejs function never returns or ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I get output from the call at the console.log() but the function doesn't properly exit or end. I'm not too familiar with async functions, but when I take out the async I don't get any output.

```
const { Client, FileCreateTransaction, Ed25519PrivateKey, Hbar, FileContentsQuery, FileId } = require("@hashgraph/sdk");
require("dotenv").config();

async function makeFile(contents) {
  const operatorAccount = process.env.OPERATOR_ID;
  const operatorPrivateKey = Ed25519PrivateKey.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_KEY);
  const operatorPublicKey = operatorPrivateKey.publicKey;

  if (operatorPrivateKey == null || operatorAccount == null) {
    throw new Error(
      "environment variables OPERATOR_KEY and OPERATOR_ID must be present"
    );
  }

  const client = Client.forTestnet()
  client.setOperator(operatorAccount, operatorPrivateKey);

  // make new file
  const transactionId = await new FileCreateTransaction()
    .setContents(contents)
    .addKey(operatorPublicKey) // Defines the "admin" of this file
    .setMaxTransactionFee(new Hbar(15))
    .execute(client);

    const receipt = await transactionId.getReceipt(client); 
    const fileId = receipt.getFileId();
    return fileId;
}

async function main()
{
  let id = await makeFile(process.argv[2]);
  console.log(id);
  return id;
}

main()
```

EDIT: So it does fully run, but it takes a while (over a minute or so) which is really impractical actually.

Comment: able to debug `transactionId.getReceipt`?

Comment: Have you try to write ``console.log(fileId)`` inside the makeFile function?

Comment: yes, i've tried both and they both work

Comment: so, creating that file takes a minute there. is there a question left or should we close this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)